# How to apply custom search on uitextfield for place search using gmsAutocomplete view controller.?

Tags: ios, google-maps, autocomplete

> HI all i am working on GMSAutocompleteViewController in my app. i have a uitextfield in my view controller when i tapp  textfield for search a place using google api, a new view is open which is powered by google. Look at my code please.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {



tappedTextField = textField;
        GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
        acController.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];



  }


  - (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
   didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place {
// Do something with the selected place.
NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);
NSLog(@"lat and log%f", place.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"lang %f", place.coordinate.longitude);



   tappedTextField.text = place.name;



[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

  - (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
    didFailAutocompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
// TODO: handle the error.
      NSLog(@"error: %ld", (long)[error code]);
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
     }

  // User canceled the operation.
- (void)wasCancelled:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController {
NSLog(@"Autocomplete was cancelled.");
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   }
```

> i don't want to move to another view on textfield tapp for searching. is it possible that i can search places from the textfield only?

[image: Scrren of my view controller]

> when i click on destination textfield a new view is appear for searching but i need search from textfield only please at the screen after tapp the textfield.

[image: This screen after click of textfield]

Comment: is there any possibility to do this task or i always used view powered by google only?

Comment: Hi is it solved?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what you're after is to display the autocomplete results in a table immediately underneath the textfield when the text field is active (ie something similar to [this](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/8a7e4bb903d499f3f31c2134212f89cbf2c47784/68747470733a2f2f646c2e64726f70626f7875736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f752f39303831373736342f4d5047546578744669656c642e706e67)).

You can do this by creating a UITableView that you display in your UI in the right location. Instead of using `GMSAutocompleteViewController`, create a [`GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource`](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_table_data_source) and set it as the UITableView's delegate and data source. For example:

```
_tableDataSource = [[GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource alloc] init];
_tableDataSource.delegate = self;
tableView.delegate = _tableDataSource;
tableView.dataSource = _tableDataSource;
```

When the text field text changes, call `sourceTextHasChanged` on the table data source.

```
[_tableDataSource sourceTextHasChanged:textField.text];
```

Finally, have the parent view controller implement the [`GMSAutocompleteTableDataSourceDelegate`](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/protocol_g_m_s_autocomplete_table_data_source_delegate-p) protocol

There is some example code in the sample app contained in the GoogleMaps CocoaPod that is close to what you want. Look for `SDKDemoAutocompleteWithTextFieldController.m` in the downloaded Pods directory.

Comment: can u help me in the same scenario please? @AndrewR

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to achieve same behaviour you are asking.

```
-(void)LoadJson_search{
searchArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSLog(@"str......%@",strSearch);

NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%@&key=AIzaSyD2NttUhPQ4PKvpju97qpeWj8SYnZtzt0s",strSearch];
NSLog(@"%@",strSearch);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str1];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error=nil;
if(data.length==0)
{

}
else
{
    NSDictionary *jsondic= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    // NSLog(@"1,,,,%@",jsondic);
    [searchArray removeAllObjects];
    if([[jsondic objectForKey:@"status"]isEqualToString:@"ZERO_RESULTS"])
    {

    }
    else if([[jsondic objectForKey:@"status"]isEqualToString:@"INVALID_REQUEST"])
    {
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<[jsondic.allKeys count];i++)
        {
            //['predictions'][0]['description']
            NSString *str1=[[[jsondic objectForKey:@"predictions"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"description"];
            [searchArray  addObject:str1];
        }
        tbl_vw1.hidden=FALSE;
    }
    if (searchArray.count == 0) {
        tbl_vw1.hidden = TRUE;
    }
    else{
        [tbl_vw1 reloadData];
    }
}
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;{
if (textField.tag == 3) {
    strSearch = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    if([string isEqualToString:@" "]){

    }
    else{
        [self LoadJson_search];
    }
}
return YES;
}
```

And on tableview didSelect method use following

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
strSelectedAddress = [searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.eventDict setObject:strSelectedAddress forKey:@"venue"];
//[self geoCodeUsingAddress:str_select_address];

tbl_vw1.hidden=TRUE;
[tbl_vw reloadData];
}
```

after reloading table, use this in cellForRowAtIndexpath to update selected place name.

```
cell.txt.text = [self.eventDict objectForKey:@"venue"];
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Bro, i have a textfield and under it is a tableview , when user tap the textfield it show the relevant places, bro i'm not getting how to do this can u help me in this? I'm trying this first time and facing a lot of problems. @Nij

Comment: can u help me in this? @Nij

Comment: check delegate method of textfield and show your tableview according.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer based on @ Nij. This will give complete satisfaction you to ...

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <GooglePlaces/GooglePlaces.h>

@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    NSMutableArray *searchArray;
    NSString *strSearch;

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *searchTextfeild;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tbl_vw1;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _searchTextfeild.delegate = self;
    _tbl_vw1.delegate = self;
    _tbl_vw1.dataSource = self;
    _tbl_vw1.hidden = YES;

    _searchTextfeild.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)LoadJson_search{

    searchArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //    NSLog(@"str......%@",strSearch);
    // This API key is from https://developers.google.com/maps/web/
    NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=%@&key=AIzaSyAm7buitimhMgE1dKV2j4_7doULluiiDzU", strSearch];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str1];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error=nil;
    if(data.length==0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *jsondic= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    //         NSLog(@"1,,,,%@",jsondic);
        [searchArray removeAllObjects];
        if([[jsondic objectForKey:@"status"]isEqualToString:@"ZERO_RESULTS"])
        {

        }
        else if([[jsondic objectForKey:@"status"]isEqualToString:@"INVALID_REQUEST"])
        {
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0;i<[jsondic.allKeys count];i++)
            {
                NSString *str1=[[[jsondic objectForKey:@"predictions"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"description"];
                [searchArray  addObject:str1];
            }
            _tbl_vw1.hidden = NO;
    //            NSLog(@"%@", searchArray);
        }
        if (searchArray.count == 0) {
            _tbl_vw1.hidden = YES;
        }else{
            [_tbl_vw1 reloadData];
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;{
    if (textField.tag == 3) {
        strSearch = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
         if([string isEqualToString:@" "]){

         }else{
             [self LoadJson_search];
         }
    }
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField{
    _tbl_vw1.hidden = YES;
     [_tbl_vw1 reloadData];

    return YES;
}


//TableView delegates
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return searchArray.count;
}


 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tbl_vw1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
//    NSLog(@"searchArray ==== %@", searchArray);
    cell.textLabel.text = [searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    _searchTextfeild.text = [searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    _tbl_vw1.hidden = YES;
    [_tbl_vw1 reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Use main queue for reload table view data, dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_tbl_vw1 reloadData];
    });

Comment: This above code will display only two places, if you want to display more than to two places... Change json dic count like this ....   for(int i=0;i<[[jsondic objectForKey:@"predictions"] count];i++)
            {
                NSString *str1=[[[jsondic objectForKey:@"predictions"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"description"];
                [searchArray  addObject:str1];
            }